# Android studio show me the following when I run my app

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE            (Don't know how to fix)
Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE    (Don't know how to fix)
Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE         (Don't know how to fix)
Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
24 actionable tasks: 24 up-to-date
```

Comment: did you try to invalidate cache and restart then rebuild?

Comment: Since your build succeeded... what exactly is your concern? `NO-SOURCE` is not a problem on its own.